# Symfony 4.4 migrating to 6

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, deprecated, deprecation-warning

actually i made a symfony webapp 3 years ago , i didn't use it, and now i am trying to deploy it on heroku but it says , that i need to use newer version
I am trying to resolve the deprecation before updating the version (5.1 and  go progressively to 6) but i do not know how to do
i already made my research on internet but i did not find something that can help [image: Deprecation symfony]

Answer (score 1):

You should migrate to `Symfony 5` first tkans to the full doc [here](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/setup/upgrade_major.html) and after to `Symfony 6` thanks to [that](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/upgrade_major.html) !

Both explain how to fix your deprecations and a search for deprecations specific to your favorite search engine will also help!

Comment: i already looked at their docs but there is no info that help me in the docs 
there are some deprecation that i do not know to fix them

Comment: Did you look for deprecations one by one on Internet? I managed to migrate in this way an application from Symfony 3.4 to 6.2 while there was a complete change of architecture between Symfony 3 and 4 (addition of `symfony/flex`)  !  Make a little effort and especially be specific about blocking depreciations. Thank you!